# how to assign javascript variable value to jsp tag attribute?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

**I have a drop down value list, and user will select a value from this dropdown list.**

```
<strong>SelectPageCount: </strong>
    <select id="pageCount" onChange = "setPageSizeValue();">
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="150">150</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="250">250</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
    </select>
```

**I have got the value of the dropdown list in this javascript function.**

```
function setPageSizeValue()
    {
        var dropDownDocument = document.getElementById("pageCount");

        var displayElementDocument = document.getElementById("displayTable");

        var pagesize =  dropDownDocument.options[dropDownDocument.selectedIndex].value;

        displayElementDocument.setAttribute('pagesize', dropDownDocument.options[dropDownDocument.selectedIndex].value);


        alert(pagesize);

    }*
```

**alter is coming properly displaying the value which we set in the dropdown list.**

**This is our Jsp**

**In this jsp in pagesize attribute i want to assign the value of pagesize varialbe made in javascript.**

```
<display:table id="displayTable" name="ewCandidateList" sort="list" pagesize="<%=size %>" requestURI="CandidateSearchResult"   
 decorator="com.thomsonreuters.legal.lem.lpa.ui.decorator.EWCandidateSearchResultDecorator"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change, on the client side (JS), a variable that is computed on the server side (JSP). It's not possible...

What you can do is create a form and submit it, have a hidden input element that will be posted by the form to the JSP and then re-render the page with the new value. But you probably don't want to do anything like that as well.

What you really want to do is insert all the content of the display-table into a div, and change the [size of the div using javascript](http://www.css-resources.com/Change-Div-Size-Color-and-Location-with-the-W3C-DOM.htm).